# jQuery and resize() don't work

Tags: jquery, html, resize

I have a list for my menu, i use method resize on jQuery to resize li but if my page is reduced, works because when i try to increase the page my li increase but if my page is full and i try to reduce my li don't reduces. What i can do?

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      size();
      $(window).resize(size);
    });
    function size() {
      var tr = $( "#nav li ul" ).width();   
              $("#nav li ul li").width(tr);
    }
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="navi">
        <li ><a class="first" href="\">Home</a></li>
        <li><font>Test</font>
          <ul>
            <li><a>Test 1</a></li>
            <li class="last"><a >Test 2</a></li>
          </ul>
          <div class="clear"></div>
        </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: You have to remove the width of the nested `li` before measuring the width of the parent because the child `li` will hold the parent `ul` open. Do you even need to use JS for this? CSS is pretty good at making a child 100% the width of its parent.

Comment: Your `#nav` element is missing, then `$( "#nav li ul" )` returns null

Comment: It's a little difficult to tell what you are trying to do. Could you post a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or a snippet illustrating the problem?

Comment: This is the code http://jsfiddle.net/0hnuohty/

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the width of the nested `li` before measuring the width of the parent because the child `li` will hold the parent `ul` open.

```
function size() {
    $( "#nav li ul li" ).css('width', 'auto'); // <-- remove the child's width
    var tr = $( "#nav li ul" ).width(); 
    $("#nav li ul li").width(tr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
$(function() {
    $(window).resize( function()
    {
        var tr = $( "#nav li ul" ).width();   
        $("#nav li ul li").width(tr);
    });
});
```